Failing Script to keep teams user available
I have a (hopefully) small Problem with a script I wrote.
I have 2 dummy users in Teams, which aren't related to anyone and noone can access them since they are just used to forward calls.
Now we need them to be available so they can be called by a queue.
The script I wrote know tells me that its missing a "=" at a hashliteral on three different lines.
# Graph API Details
$tenantId = "***"
$clientId = "***"
$clientSecret = "***"
 
# Function to get OAuth token
function Get-OAuthToken {
    param (
        [string]$tenantId,
        [string]$clientId,
        [string]$clientSecret
    )
 
    $body = @{
        grant_type    = "client_credentials"
        scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        client_id     = $clientId
        client_secret = $clientSecret
    }
 
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token" -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
    return $response.access_token
}
 
# Get the OAuth token
$token = Get-OAuthToken -tenantId $tenantId -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret
 
# Users to keep online
$users = @("")
 
# Function to set user presence status to available
function Set-UserPresence {
    param (
        [string]$user,
        [string]$token
    )
 
    $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$user/presence/setPresence"
    $headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $token"
        Content-Type  = "application/json"
        }
    $body = @{
        sessionId     = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
        availability  = "Available"
        activity      = "Available"
        expirationDuration = "PT1H"
    }
 
    $jsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody
}
 
# Loop to keep users online
while ($true) {
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        Set-UserPresence -user $user -token $token
        Write-Output "Set presence to Available for $user at $(Get-Date)"
    }
 
    # Wait for 5 minutes before setting the presence again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
}

I tried counting brackets and looked for any missing commas or something like that, but I didnt find anything.
Maybe someone on here has better eyes than me or an idea what problem it could be if not some missing bracket
Thanks in advance

On line 41, the Content-Type key may not contain a HYPHEN-MINUS (-) character. Will Content_Type work? Or perhaps, "Content-Type". I found this using PSScriptAnalyzer and by opening the file in the VS Code editor.

Yes thank you, with the quotes it goes through.
Now I just have to find out why I'm not authorized to Post that request

Hash table keys that are strings that must be quoted if they contain a HYPHEN-MINUS (-) character. Content-Type must be quoted to be a key for the $headers hash.
Change:
Content-Type = "application/json"

to:
'Content-Type' = "application/json"

Experimentation at the console command line.
PS C:\src\t\pscoretest> $h = @{a=2;b=3;c-c=2}
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  $h = @{a=2;b=3;c-c=2}
     |                  ~
     | Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
PS C:\src\t\pscoretest> $h = @{a=2;b=3;'c-c'=2}
PS C:\src\t\pscoretest> $h

Name                           Value
----                           -----
b                              3
a                              2
c-c                            2

Output from the PSScriptAnalyzer module.
PS C:\src\t> Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Path .\afile.ps1

RuleName                            Severity     ScriptName Line  Message
--------                            --------     ---------- ----  -------
MissingEqualsInHashLiteral          ParseError   afile.ps1  41    Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
PSUseShouldProcessForStateChangingF Warning      afile.ps1  32    Function 'Set-UserPresence' has verb that could change
unctions                                                          system state. Therefore, the function has to support
                                                                  'ShouldProcess'.

